# Contact form 7 PVB Contact Form 7 age calculate

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to use the formula "[calculation calculation-age"(date-todaydate- date-birthdate)/365.2425"]" to calculate age but once I entered birth year 1950 or less I get the result as "0"

What causing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you create custom short code ?

Comment: No, as shown in here I used the PVB plugin to calculate. I used the code as shown above but the result appears only for 49 years. If I add birth year as 1969, result appears as "0".

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: can you share your plugin url?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pvb-contact-form-7-calculator/. I have purchased the pro version but its the same.